# Roasting nuts in a rotisserie drum

Tags: roasting, nuts, rotisserie

I have a rotisserie drum like this:

[image: Rotisserie Drum]

I would like to roast peanuts, cashew nuts, etc... in this. If I use the settings given for roasting the nuts in a baking tray, the nuts seem under-cooked consistently.

Is there a general rule for using the rotisserie drum? Like a conversion factor? Also, is it better to use the drum to roast nuts instead of the tray? I wanted to use the drum because of the uniformity in roasting that can be obtained.

Answer (score 5):

Different ovens and air-fryers perform differently, hence I don't think there is a one- size-fits-all kind of a conversion factor. In my case, I roast a kilo of peanuts in one go and it takes 22-24 minutes and another 9 minutes of the free heat from the cooling down. I have another air-fryer that stops operating at the set time and does not offer free cooling down heat and so I air-fry for perhaps 29-30 minutes.

I suggest you invest in a kilograms of peanuts and experiment with the duration. Be prepared to write off losses. Also, do not to expose the air-fryer to the sun. You fryer will suffer for it.

Cashew nuts and hazel nuts brown faster, about half the time of peanuts. You absolutely do not want to roast as long as for peanuts.

Using drum is undoubtedly superior to tray. With a tray, you probably need to stir at least once to get a more even roasting and yet still can't beat drum-roasting.

You can also roast green coffee beans with drums.

Answer (score 1):

I have exactly the same looking rotisserie basket and I've tried it for about 250g of skinless cashew nuts which turned out quite nicely. 180 degrees Celsius for 12 mins, no need to preheat.